# Ruby on Rails bundler

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, bundler

I am using Ruby version 2.6.6. Rails version 5.2.3. But my bundler version is 2.1.4 Will I run in to any issues because of this? should I downgrade my bundler? If so please tell me how.

Answer (score 0):

No, you will not face any issues because of this. Only thing is that rarely you can face issues because of using a recent version of Ruby, like "2.6.6". Also, this is not specific for Ruby, it's valid for every programming language. But I don't think it will stop you from doing anything. Have a nice day!

Comment: Oh okay thanks! just been trying to get in to web development. Thanks for clearing that up :) Hope you have a nice day too !

Comment: Also could you let me know how I can downgrade me ruby version to <2.5?

Comment: I believe you need to search for "rvm" it's like a package management system for ruby. Also if you're considering that because of my answer, don't worry about it. It's a low chance(0.01%) to face an issue because of that.